# BibLaTeX unique identifier arabic

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, formatting

I'm using the `alphabetic` biblatex style and have to format my sources the following way, if there are two sources with the same author:

- either as "KEY-1" (where `-1` replaces `a`)
- or as "KEY<sup>1</sup>" (where `1` replaces `a`).

How can I achieve this?

Current status:

[image: references]

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[backend=biber,style=alphabetic,maxbibnames=1,maxcitenames=1,defernumbers,%
    doi=false,isbn=false,clearlang=false,backref=false]{biblatex}
\DeclareFieldFormat{labelalpha}{\textsc{#1}}

\begin{filecontents}{bib.bib}
@ONLINE{text:source,
    author={B. Obby},
    title={Sources today},
    url={http://www.example.com},
    urldate={2017-02-20},}
@ONLINE{text:src,
    author={B. Obby},
    title={Sources tomorrow},
    url={http://www.example.com},
    urldate={2017-02-20},}
\end{filecontents}

\bibliography{bib}
\nocite{*}

\begin{document}

Text with citation: \autocite{text:source}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\DeclareFieldFormat{extraalpha}{#1}`?

Comment: @moewe Thanks. I've searched in the documentation for anything with unique, but didn't see that there was a field for that purpose and style. Could you please post your comment as answer?

Comment: @moewe I was wondering who chooses the name of `biblatex` options, shouldn't something like `labelsuffix` have been better? :):):):)

Comment: @CarLaTeX I really agree with you. They are not self-explaining and very hard to find, if you do not know very much about `biblatex`'s mechanisms.

Comment: Exactly! You're not the only one who have searched an option for "hours" and then discovers that it has an unthinkable name! :):):):):):)

Comment: @CarLaTeX Mhhh, this seems to be in analogy to `extrayear` (the letter added to the year if needed). There is `labelprefix`, which the user can set herself unlike `extraalpha`.

Comment: @moewe Even `extrayear` is not much clear... also in that case I'd have chosen `yearsuffix`... :)

Comment: @CarLaTeX I may be a bit biased since I have worked with it for so long, but I actually think the 'extra' makes it clear that this is not something that is always applied, but a little extra if needed. 'suffix' (in analogy to the 'prefix' in `labelprefix`) on the other hand is always there.

Comment: @moewe Next time you developers have to choose a name, do a poll on Meta! :):):):):):

Comment: @CarLaTeX That's a great idea. I would definitely participate!

Comment: @CarLaTeX No, I didn't receive it.

Comment: Visit our chat! I think you are a smart user (the other one has no points) and sooner or later someone would like talk with you without choosing the wrong TeXnician!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @moewe suggested, it is very simple: `\DeclareFieldFormat{extraalpha}{#1}` is sufficient to fullfill the task, because it is as customizable as every field format.